# I want to push latitude and longitude object in an array angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to push latitude and longitude object in an array in angular.js please help me.

```
$scope.showPosition = function showPosition() {
    var watchOptions = {timeout : 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

    watch.then(
        null,
        function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        },
        function(position) {
          var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          var long = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.lat = lat;
          $scope.long = long;
          console.log(lat + '' + long)
        }
    );
    // watch.clearWatch();
  };
```

Comment: The first argument of the `.then` is the success callback. So in there do something like `function(response) { $scope.coordinates = response; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$scope.GeoLocationArray = [];
$scope.showPosition = function showPosition() {
    var watchOptions = {timeout : 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

    watch.then(
        null,
        function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        },
        function(position) {
          var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          var long = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.lat = lat;
          $scope.long = long;
          $scope.GeoLocationArray.push({
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long
          })
          console.log(lat + '' + long)
        }
    );
    // watch.clearWatch();
  };
```

Comment: Does this meets your discussion?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to push latitude and longitude object in an array

```
function(position) {
  var array = [];
  var object = {
      lat:position.coords.latitude,
      long:position.coords.longitude
  };
  array.push(object);
  console.log(array[0].lat + '' + array[0].long);
}
```

or directly

```
function(position) {
  var array = [];
  array.push(position.coords);
  console.log(array[0].latitude + '' + array[0].longitude);
}
```

That's an answer to your question, but maybe you haven't formulated the question correctly for your purpose.